# Redirect host name to other

Tags: 14.04, server, hostname

I added a row in `/etc/hosts`:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx new.office
```

I now need all the calls that I do on `old.office` redirected to `new.office`.

Is there a way to do it? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Comment: the situation is slightly different now.

new.office is the host name associated with a dynamic dns service

Comment: If it was a name associated with a DynDNS, why did you add an entry to static `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: I was waiting for the service became active. what interests me is not so much of ip resolution new.office but the association of old.office to new.office

Comment: Sorry, but if you have a question, please specify it and don't rely on other people to pull the very basic information from you. What you want (but what is it really?) is hard to do. This is an [old thread](http://serverfault.com/q/137912/197039), but the conclusion (Alnitak's answer) holds true.

Comment: I think on my server is installed bind9. It does not make me use dnsmasq because the port is already occupied

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking there is no way to "redirect" from `old.office` to `new.office`.

What you can do is add `old.office` in the same line, so that it will resolve to the same IP address:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx new.office old.office
```

Of course if you have `old.office` currently defined in `/etc/hosts`, you need to remove it.

Comment: What about `iptables` and prerouting

Comment: @EdiD I don't understand your comment.

Comment: With `iptables` you can redirect from one ip to another

Comment: @EdiD So what? I said that name redirection was impossible, is it? If you have another solution for OP just write it as a different answer.

Comment: thanks for reply. i add more information about my problem. See comment under question.